# Use variable in other part of the document

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to echo the variable $row in a table. But it's not really working. Isn't $row global? I thought variables are only local when they are inside of a function.
    ...

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["teacherID"] . " " . $row["shorthand"] . " " . $row["votes"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

...

<td><?php echo $row["shorthand"]; ?></td>
```

Comment: you probably want to put that in your loop? And what does "not really working" mean?

Comment: @ElefantPhace what do i want to put in the loop? "not really working" means that there's no output

Comment: Why are you trying to echo row data outside of the loop pulling the rows from the sql result?

Comment: because i want to display parts of the sql content in my document

Comment: you do that in your while loop, where you're already `echo`ing them anyway

Comment: yes, but i need it to echo in the table. (i am new to php) :)

Comment: do that in you're while loop. Are you really wanting to display the same things twice?

Comment: no, but how do i echo it into the table in my while loop?

Comment: Your loop makes sense, but the last line does not. Which `$row` do you intend to use with the last line of code?

Comment: @Ahmad the $row of the loop

Comment: @SimonMathewson I know.. but there are multiple `$row`s in that loop. Are you using $row inside another loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking to do something like this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["teacherID"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["shorthand"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["votes"]. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

If you have other rows/columns in your table you should be able to figure out how to fit them into this